# Updating to .Net Core 3.1.12 caused 3.1.0 sites to break

Tags: asp.net-core

Over the weekend our webserver was updated, and after that our website went down with the error "HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies", and we received this error message in the event log on all sites using .Net Core 3.1.0:

**"The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.12' was not found."**

When we uninstalled 3.1.12, the sites came back online.

Is there a way to allow for .Net Core updates without sites going down?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.3' was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61682415/the-framework-microsoft-aspnetcore-app-version-3-1-3-was-not-found)

Comment: It broke because you installed the runtime, not the hosting bundle. Please try reading the error message next time.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly. installing the 3.1.12 "Hosting Bundle" would have also resolved the problem?   We saw the runtime was installed and thought that was it, but I guess it was not all that was needed.  If that is the case, thanks.

Comment: In regard to the other SO question, the answer with the same download link is not the accepted answer.  The question is also not similar to mine in that it refers to a developer machine not the web server.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61682415/the-framework-microsoft-aspnetcore-app-version-3-1-3-was-not-found

Comment: In case nobody answers this (just downvotes instead) I think our IT staff have found the culprit.  There is a known issue with Windows Update not resolve host bundles correctly.  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-updates-coming-to-microsoft-update/   “Note: updates for the Hosting Bundle won’t be available on MU initially while we work through a couple of issues. These updates will need to be downloaded and deployed from our download website. We will update this post once the issue is corrected and we are ready to start delivering updates for the hosting bundle via MU.”